# Custom dependency property of image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have little problem. I want to create custom control and this custom control should have Custom dependencyproperty of type Image. I want to be able to change Image of specific control in design time like it is in standard Image Control. I tried to do it like this:

```
    public ImageSource IconImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconImageSourceProperty); }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(IconImageSourceProperty, value);
            img_Icon.Source = value;

        }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty IconImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(NavigationMenuItem));
```

then set image source in xaml file like this:

```
<local:NavigationMenuItem IconImageSource="/res/DarkMode/NavigationMenuItem_Home.png"/>
```

App is compiling without problem, but it doesnt show my image. Honestly I dont understand what's wrong here, I tried to debug this but I just cant. I set breakpoint in set but it didnt even stopped, like set wouldnt be even launched once. I dont have any idea how can I fix this. I tried to change type to Uri, BitmapImage but nothing helped Can anyone help me please?

Comment: "set breakpoint in set but it didnt even stopped, like set wouldnt be even launched once" - that is true. but property IconImageSourceProperty was assigned because wpf called `SetValue()` method directly

Comment: You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback.